# The most elegant method for determing if two positions in a grid are adjacent

Tags: actionscript-3

And by adjacent, I only mean one unit left, right, up, or down. Diagonals don't count. You know the x,y grid coordinates of both positions.

Ultimately this is for AS3, but answers in pseudo code would be sufficient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
abs(a.x - b.x) + abs(a.y - b.y) == 1
```

Answer (score 3):

(a.x - b.x) ^ 2 + (a.y - b.y) ^ 2 = 1

Comment: Squaring the values is completely redundant (1 ^ 2 = 1)

Comment: not true... it's purposed is to correct the sign when a.x - b.x = -1 or a.y - b.y = -1 (just as 'abs' does in the accepted answer)

Comment: Squaring is more expensive though I'd think.